# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'name' of 'Employee.Employee(string,string, int)'

Tags: c#

I have this `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    
    public Employee(string name, string dateOfBirth, int phoneNumber)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;

    }
}
```

In this program:

```
namespace modelMIP
{
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var angajat = new Employee()
            {
                Name = "ion",
                DateOfBirth = "28",
                PhoneNumber = 0770335978
                
            };
            Console.WriteLine(angajat); 
        }
        
    }
        
}
```

i have to create a ToString method for showing an object in this format :
Name | DateOfBirth | PhoneNumber
can anyone help me? what is the problem ?

Comment: thank you ! helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

The Employee constructor takes three arguments, but you're not passing any: `new Employee()`.

You could simply change your initializers to passed constructor arguments:

```
            var angajat = new Employee("ion", "28", 0770335978);
```

If you like having the properties named, you can use parameter names:

```
var angajat = new Employee(
    name: "ion", 
    dateOfBirth: "28", 
    phoneNumber: 0770335978);
```

Or you could give your `Employee` class a constructor that takes no arguments, and rely on users to initialize properties they want to initialize.

```
    public Employee()
    {
    }
```

This latter would be more dangerous in some ways because people could easily forget to initialize the values.

You may also want to consider using C# 9's new `record` feature.

```
public record Employee(string Name, string DateOfBirth, int PhoneNumber);
```

```
    var angajat = new Employee(
        Name: "ion",
        DateOfBirth: "28",
        PhoneNumber: 0770335978);
```

The ToString() method, in either case, can look like this:

```
    public override string ToString() => $"{Name} | {DateOfBirth} | {PhoneNumber}";
```

Comment: @Davyyd: Glad I could help. If your question is fully answered, you should accept an answer so other people know you're not still looking for help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to use a default constructor that doesn't exist. Normally, C# will create a default constructor for you... *unless you provide a constructor of your own*. You did provide a constructor of your own: one that requires three arguments.

Therefore, this code is not valid, because there's no matching constructor for the `Employee` employee type:

```
var angajat = new Employee()
{
    Name = "ion",
    DateOfBirth = "28",
    PhoneNumber = 0770335978            
};
```

The object initializer syntax is *not the same thing* as calling your constructor. You want this, instead:

```
var angajat = new Employee("ion", "28", 0770335978);
```

Or change the type to also have a default constructor:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    // Default constructor
    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(string name, string dateOfBirth, int phoneNumber)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Either or both will work. Then you can also override `ToString()`:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(string name, DateTime dateOfBirth, string phoneNumber)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name,-20}|{DateOfBirth,12:d} | {PhoneNumber}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var angajat = new Employee("ion", "28", 0770335978);
```

You are using a constructor that required you to fill in the parameters to construct the Employee object.

Go learn about [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)